# Problem with a part of Dynkin's first theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An Italian book of mine goes on to prove Dynkin's first theorem as stated:

$ 
Let\ \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}) \ be \ the \ monotone \ family \ generated\ by \ \mathcal{A}, \ where \ \mathcal{A} \ is \ a \ family \ of \ subsets \ of \ \Omega. \ If \ \mathcal{A} \ is \bigcap-stable, then \\ 
 \begin{gather*}  \mathcal{M} (\mathcal{A}) = \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \\ \end{gather*} $

After some considerations the book wants to prove that $\mathcal{M_1} \ = \{A \in \mathcal{M} \ | \ A \ \cap \ I \in \mathcal{M}, \forall I \in \mathcal{A} \}  $ is a monotone family (pay attention to the notation of the A and the $\mathcal{A}$ this confused me at first).

The book then says that after proving this the next statements are implied: $ \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{M_1} , \mathcal{M} \subseteq \mathcal{M_1} $ and consequently $  \mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M_1} $ .

I am having some problems on the "consequently" I understand the two statements  that come before $ \mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M_1} $ but not this one.  $ \mathcal{M_1} $ is a superset of both $ \mathcal{A} $ and $ \mathcal{M} $ but why do we have also $ \mathcal{M_1} \supseteq  \mathcal{M}  $ ?

Comment: It is clear from the definition of $\mathcal M_I$ that it is a subset of $\mathcal M$.

Comment: No (general-topology) here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you understand that $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{M}_1$, and also that $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{M}_1$. I assume $\mathcal{M}$ is the same as your $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ from the first line.

So we now know that $\mathcal{M}_1$ is a monotone family (proved before), contains $\mathcal{A}$ (first statement), so $\mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}) \subset \mathcal{M}_1$, because the monotone family generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is by definition the *smallest* (by inclusion) monotone family that contains $\mathcal{A}$ as a subset, and $\mathcal{M}_1$ is one such monotone family, so $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ is a subset of it by minimality.

The second statement is just the other inclusion, so we have equality.